# Android resource linking failed only on my foreground drawables not my background ones

Tags: android

I am trying to create an .aab file to post my app to play store but im getting a android resource linking failed on only my foreground drawbales of my bottom navigation,

xml of one of the drawables:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    android:viewportHeight="108"
    android:tint="#000000">
  <group android:scaleX="2.61"
      android:scaleY="2.61"
      android:translateX="22.68"
      android:translateY="22.68">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M13,3c-4.97,0 -9,4.03 -9,9L1,12l3.89,3.89 0.07,0.14L9,12L6,12c0,-3.87 3.13,-7 7,-7s7,3.13 7,7 -3.13,7 -7,7c-1.93,0 -3.68,-0.79 -4.94,-2.06l-1.42,1.42C8.27,19.99 10.51,21 13,21c4.97,0 9,-4.03 9,-9s-4.03,-9 -9,-9zM12,8v5l4.28,2.54 0.72,-1.21 -3.5,-2.08L13.5,8L12,8z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

My bottom nav xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_foreground"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/workout"
        android:title="Workout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_workout_foreground"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:title="History"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_foreground"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you added your resources in debug folder - which means that you can run the debug version of the app from android studio, but when you try to create a release one the compiler can not find the resource. Check your resource parent folder/finder/explorer and if so ^^, move your resource file

from

> app/src/***debug***/resources/drawable/

to

> app/src/***main***/resources/drawable/

Comment: you are right i just noticed they are in the debug but how i move them to the main in android studio?

Comment: in my answer I have mentioned it, just move from  app/src/debug/resources/drawable/  -> to   -> app/src/main/resources/drawable/